# desinstalar apache en mac

Tags: php, apache2

tengo un problema con mi apache en mac, el problema es que lo intente actualizar y despues de eso en el navegador cuando escribo localhost me manda el siguiente mensaje:
La conexión se reinició
La conexión al servidor se reinició mientras se cargaba la página.

mi pregunta es: hay alguna manera de desinstalarlo y volverlo a instalar?
o si alguien sabe el porque dejo de funcionar?

Comment: si ahorita lo acabo de reiniciar y nada, me sigue mandando el mismo mensaje (La conexión se reinició
La conexión al servidor se reinició mientras se cargaba la página.)

Comment: A mi me suena que puede ser un problema de firewall por que estás iniciando la conexión y luego parece que te la corta puedes intentar hacer un wget, y después ver si te contesta, para instalar wget en mac necesitas https://www.macports.org/install.php

Comment: y como hago un wget